# MVC4 DevExpress Date Edit control:state management

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass values of selected date in date edit control,from view to controller through javascript event,using e.customArgs["variable"].Please find below code:

On Buttonclick:

```
function OnClickShowLog(s, e) {
                 SelectedTimestampFlag = 999;
                 alert(SelectedTimestampFlag);                 
                selectedStartDate = DateEditStartdate.GetValue();
                alert(selectedStartDate );

}
```

On BeginCallback:

```
function OnBeginCallback(s, e) {

                    if (SelectedTimestampFlag != null) {

                        e.customArgs["StartDateValue"] = selectedStartDate;
                        alert("startdate:" + e.customArgs["StartDateValue"]);

                        e.customArgs["SelectedTimestampFlag"] = SelectedTimestampFlag;
                        alert("timestamp:" + e.customArgs["SelectedTimestampFlag"]);
                    }
              }
```

If i am accessing **Request.Params["SelectedTimestampFlag"]** it is returning correct value on mvc controller but ,when i m trying to access e.customArgs["StartDateValue"] on controller using **Request.Params["StartDateValue"]** it is returning null.Please suggest.

Comment: Pass the value in string format and convert it into dateTime  inside the controller

Comment: Thanks Mahesh..what i did is this:selectedStartDate = DateEditStartdate.GetText(); instead of--> selectedStartDate = DateEditStartdate.GetValue(); and it worked